# FastVectorHighlighter.Net returning null on GetBestFragment

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, highlighter.net, fast-vector-highlighter

I have a large index, on which Highlighter.Net works fine, but FastVectorHighlighter returns null as a Best Fragment on Some documents.

the searcher works fine. It is just the highlighter. The field has been indexed in the same manner for all documents, so I fail to understand Why it highlights some documents but not all.

Using Lucene.Net 2.9.2, built from trunk rev942061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by the nice people at lucene-net-user. I was passing the document sequence number in the Hits object, where I should have been passing the sequence number in the lucene index. Read full mailing list thread starting [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-lucene-net-user/201005.mbox/%3Cl2g253c119c1005071102ne2bb0ec5xe7cf993133a341dc@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Answer (score 0):

are you setting FieldMatch to true?

Comment: what other way have you tried? I suspect it has to do with FieldMatch try both false/true.

Comment: Yup I tried with both true/false value. I am also setting phrasehighlight to true (I need it). Still some documents are highlighted some are not